# Big Cassandra query causes daemon to crush

Tags: configuration, nosql, cassandra, out-of-memory

There is a need to read ~2.5Gb of records from cassandra 1.1.6 database running on CentOS release 6.3 virtual machine. When daemon with default out-of-the-box configuration is queried, i get error :

```
 INFO [Thread-2] 2012-10-30 20:05:13,345 CassandraDaemon.java (line 212) Listening for thrift clients...
 WARN [ScheduledTasks:1] 2012-10-30 20:06:27,076 GCInspector.java (line 145) Heap is 0.8434091049049706 full.  You may need to reduce memtable and/or
 WARN [ScheduledTasks:1] 2012-10-30 20:06:27,077 StorageService.java (line 2855) Flushing CFS(Keyspace='system', ColumnFamily='Versions') to relieve m
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2012-10-30 20:06:27,077 ColumnFamilyStore.java (line 659) Enqueuing flush of Memtable-Versions@1970754472(83/103 serialized/l
 INFO [FlushWriter:2] 2012-10-30 20:06:27,078 Memtable.java (line 264) Writing Memtable-Versions@1970754472(83/103 serialized/live bytes, 3 ops)
 INFO [FlushWriter:2] 2012-10-30 20:06:27,096 Memtable.java (line 305) Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/Versions/system-Versions-hf-1
 WARN [ScheduledTasks:1] 2012-10-30 20:06:28,793 GCInspector.java (line 139) Heap is 0.9390217139392345 full.  You may need to reduce memtable and/or
 WARN [ScheduledTasks:1] 2012-10-30 20:06:28,794 AutoSavingCache.java (line 156) Reducing KeyCache capacity from 2075306 to 12 to reduce memory pressu
 WARN [ScheduledTasks:1] 2012-10-30 20:06:28,794 GCInspector.java (line 145) Heap is 0.9390217139392345 full.  You may need to reduce memtable and/or
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2012-10-30 20:06:28,795 StorageService.java (line 2851) Unable to reduce heap usage since there are no dirty column families
 WARN [ScheduledTasks:1] 2012-10-30 20:06:30,181 GCInspector.java (line 145) Heap is 0.9984246325381808 full.  You may need to reduce memtable and/or
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2012-10-30 20:06:30,182 StorageService.java (line 2851) Unable to reduce heap usage since there are no dirty column families
 WARN [ScheduledTasks:1] 2012-10-30 20:06:34,740 GCInspector.java (line 145) Heap is 0.9983338780063149 full.  You may need to reduce memtable and/or
 INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2012-10-30 20:06:34,741 StorageService.java (line 2851) Unable to reduce heap usage since there are no dirty column families
ERROR [ReadStage:33] 2012-10-30 20:06:34,843 AbstractCassandraDaemon.java (line 135) Exception in thread Thread[ReadStage:33,5,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
<------>at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.RandomAccessReader.readBytes(RandomAccessReader.java:323)
<------>at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.read(ByteBufferUtil.java:398)
<------>at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.readWithLength(ByteBufferUtil.java:363)
<------>at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnSerializer.deserialize(ColumnSerializer.java:120)
<------>at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.ColumnIterator.deserializeNext(ColumnSortedMap.java:255)
<------>at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.ColumnIterator.next(ColumnSortedMap.java:275)
<------>at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.ColumnIterator.next(ColumnSortedMap.java:232)
<------>at edu.stanford.ppl.concurrent.SnapTreeMap.<init>(SnapTreeMap.java:453)
<------>at org.apache.cassandra.db.AtomicSortedColumns$Holder.<init>(AtomicSortedColumns.java:311)
<------>at org.apache.cassandra.db.AtomicSortedColumns.<init>(AtomicSortedColumns.java:77)
<------>at org.apache.cassandra.db.AtomicSortedColumns.<init>(AtomicSortedColumns.java:48)
<------>at org.apache.cassandra.db.AtomicSortedColumns$1.fromSorted(AtomicSortedColumns.java:61)
<------>at org.apache.cassandra.db.SuperColumnSerializer.deserialize(SuperColumn.java:399)
<------>at org.apache.cassandra.db.SuperColumnSerializer.deserialize(SuperColumn.java:382)
<------>at org.apache.cassandra.db.SuperColumnSerializer.deserialize(SuperColumn.java:377)
<------>at org.apache.cassandra.db.SuperColumnSerializer.deserialize(SuperColumn.java:339)
<------>at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.SimpleSliceReader.computeNext(SimpleSliceReader.java:79)
<------>at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.SimpleSliceReader.computeNext(SimpleSliceReader.java:39)
<------>at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:140)
<------>at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:135)
<------>at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.SSTableSliceIterator.hasNext(SSTableSliceIterator.java:116)
<------>at org.apache.cassandra.utils.MergeIterator$Candidate.advance(MergeIterator.java:147)
```

Don't have much time for calculating size of heap/memory tables etc., added

```
JVM_OPTS="-Xms4g -Xmx4g"
```

to daemon config (test server has 8 gigs of ram). Query fails again with

```
ERROR [ReadStage:1] 2012-10-30 20:46:22,417 AbstractCassandraDaemon.java (line 135) Exception in thread Thread[ReadStage:1,5,main]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.RangeSliceVerbHandler.doVerb(RangeSliceVerbHandler.java:71)
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessageDeliveryTask.run(MessageDeliveryTask.java:59)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FastByteArrayOutputStream.<init>(FastByteArrayOutputStream.java:78)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.DataOutputBuffer.<init>(DataOutputBuffer.java:40)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.RangeSliceReply.getReply(RangeSliceReply.java:48)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.RangeSliceVerbHandler.doVerb(RangeSliceVerbHandler.java:64)
        ... 4 more
```

and i can't debug further. Does anyone knows how can i tweak Cassandra so i can run that query? Database have ~500 of supercolumns ~7 mb each. I need to read them all and at some point have in memory (client machine has 40 gigs of ram so thats 100% not a lacking resources issue) for further processing. Query result is not returned into api at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should generally use 8G RAM or even 16G ram for cassandra per recommendations.

What query are you running?  I know PlayOrm uses a cursor so it gives you stuff in pieces so it won't run out of memory.  We have easily retrieved 100Gigs of stuff with PlayOrm and cassandra into our client though we discard it as it streams back and we have had no issues doing that.

later,
Dean

Comment: I have literally unlimited resources, so that's not a problem. I will increase virtual machine RAM to 20G and do JVM_OPTS="-Xms16g -Xmx16g" for cassandra executable. Are there any other settings to be changed? Looked into cassandra.yaml and found nothing relevant (there was some setting for page size but now it's deprecated). About query - i'm doing something like SELECT * FROM Table (which is columnFamily.Get() in my fluentCassandra managed api and translated in get_slice thrift method). I don't have supercolumn ids neither know how much rows are in database so i can't see other way to read.

Comment: well, there is a bit of OS settings outside of YAML like turning off swap(no swap is way better than hitting swap), and turning up the file descriptor limit, etc. etc.  I am not sure what fluentCassandra does under the covers so won't be of much help, you may want to add your cassandra version to the post though.